# ExpectedException on TestMethod Visual Studio 2010

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Today I upgraded my solution with all the underlying projects from VS2008 to VS2010. Everything went well except for my unit tests.

First of all only the web projects had as target framework .NET 4. All the other projects still had .NET 3.5. I changed them all to .NET 4.

Now when I debug my unit tests it breaks on every exception. In 2008 it just wouldn't pass and tell me that an exception occurred. Even when I have the ExpectedException attribute defined it stops debugging on every exception.

And example of one of my tests:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(EntityDoesNotExistException))]
public void ConstructorTest()
{
    AddressType type = new AddressType(int.MaxValue);
}
```

The EntityDoesNotExistException is a custom exception and inherits Exception.

**Edit**
I looked at the Exceptions settings (ctrl+alt+e) in 2008 and 2010. In both versions the settings are the same. However in 2008 the debug doesn't break when I have the ExpectedException attribute. In 2010 it does break.

Comment: Do the tests have different result? Does the expected exception still work? Is it just different when debugging?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Microsoft, this is not a bug, it's "by design":

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/511897/expectedexception-still-causes-debugging-to-break-with-exception-was-unhandled-by-user-code

Comment: Don't understand why this changed in VS2010. But thanks for showing me Microsoft has a different opinion about it.

Answer (score 12):

Gerrie pointed me in the right direction:

- Press Ctrl-Alt-E
- Open the Common Language Runtime Excepions Node
- Click Add
- Type Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException
- Make sure that both checkboxes are unchecked.

This will get rid of the break on failed Asserts, but the test will still break when you have set an ExpectedException.

I was the one that set the 100 bonus for this, so some upvotes would be appreciated ;-)

Comment: I added the entry, and it didn't work for me (VS2015 r3). What do you mean by "both checkboxes are unchecked". I unchecked the one I added (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException). What's the other checkbox to uncheck?

Answer (score 2):

Press Ctrl+Alt+E and check the break on exception setting for CLR exceptions. If this is set to true then the behavior you described will occur.

Comment: That means this has been changed in 2010? Are those settings project or solution depended?

Comment: I have two options: break on exception is thrown and break on exception is user-unhandled. Only the last option is checked for CLR exceptions.

Comment: Part of the solution indeed starts here. See my own answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

A Microsoft support guy told me to use Ctrl-F5 (start without debugging) when running my unit tests, and that seems to work.

Another thing to try is to go to Tools|Options|Debugging
and un-check the "Enable Just My Code" option.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestingFramework is Version 10.0.0.0.

If it is version 9.0.0.0 this problem will occur in Visual Studio 2010.

Hope this helps. If people still have this problem.

Comment: @John: It is not because 2008 does not support expected exceptions. It's because the attribute classes are not the same. If you reference the test framework of 2008, the compiler puts the attributes of 2008 on your test class. The test runner only checks for the attribute of 2010 (different assembly => different class), so it doesn't recognize the attribute at all. We had the same problem.

Comment: Stefan explained well what I was trying to say. :)

Answer (score 1):

I second what rlandster said.  Clearing the "Enable Just My Code" debugging option fixed this for me.  It fixed both breaking on assers and breaking on expected exceptions.  There's a little more detail on this at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/25bdf149-5133-4f47-bbf2-1d4ca638fee9.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, but finally managed to get it working. Not really sure how but here's a list of things I did between it not working to when it started working again.

- Converted the project being tested to .NET 4
- Turned off CodeCoverage
- Turned CodeCoverage back on again
- Did a RebuildAll on the test project

Not sure which bit fixed it though. Anyway, hope this helps!

Comment: I have VS2010 Professional. Code coverage only is available in Premium and Ultimate. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Something else that I think I did was go on Test->Edit Test Settings and then did a Save As, over writing the previous file. In theory this shouldn't have an effect but I did read that someone deleted his test settings file and that sorted his issue. HTH

Comment: Unfortunately this also isn't working. Really strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my tests to this form to avoid the breaking. Not ideal:

```
  [TestMethod]
  public void Guid()
  {
     try
     {
        Guid g = new Guid("myguid'123'");
     } 
     catch( FormatException fe)
     {
        return;  // expected exception - pass
     }

     Assert.Fail(); // exception not thrown - fail
  }
```