# Mstest 10.0.1.0 is not recognizing ExpectedException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, msbuild

Mstest 10.0.1.0 is not recognizing ExpectedException.

I used Msbuild to generate unit test dlls.

It seems that [ExpectedException] is not working:

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void Test(){
    throw new ArgumentNullException("test");
}
```

failed when run by mstest.

The unit test project is referencing

Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll 10.0.1.0

(^ I got this info by decompiling)

Question:

1. Is this a bug of
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll 10.0.1.0?
2. How can I make the unit test project to use fixed version 10.0.0.0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExpectedExceptionAttribute is not working in MSTest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169057/expectedexceptionattribute-is-not-working-in-mstest)

Comment: If you like to use [fluentassertions](http://www.fluentassertions.com/), you can also use following approach. This comes without _ExpectedException_ attribute
`[TestFixture]
    public class ExceptionTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            Action action = () => { throw new ArgumentNullException("test"); };
            action.ShouldThrow<ArgumentNullException>();
        }
    }`